# A Soaring Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I am important for flight,
>
> my anagram will affect your sunlight.
>
> My abbreviation is used to modify,
>
> else you would not be able to write Phi.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be

> Altitude? It's important for flight,

It's an anagram for

> "Latitude" which affects the length of the day ie. sunlight

Its abbreviation

> "Alt" like alter or alt on a keyboard.

Not sure about this-

> but perhaps Phi is a reference to [Geopotential Height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential_height) which is represented by the greek letter Phi. It could also be that in order to create the letter phi on the computer, you need to press ALT-232 (uppercase) or ALT-237 (lowercase).

Comment: You just need an explanation for that last line. Also, please use spoiler tags as to not spoil the answer for other users.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Great answer, I think this is it! :D Spoiler tags are given by >!  The last line is rot13(Va beqre gb perngr gur yrggre cuv ba gur pbzchgre, lbh arrq gb cerff NYG-232 (hccrepnfr) be NYG-237 (ybjrepnfr).) Note that to decode this, you'll need to go to [rot13.com](https://rot13.com/).

Comment: Hey I think the last line is rot13(jvgubhg gur nyg xrl, nf tvira va nooerivngvba, lbh pnaabg glcr cuv, juvpu vf nyg 237)

Comment: oh shoot LOL too slow

Comment: Thanks! I'm new here so sorry about the lack of spoiler tags, I didn't know how to make them.

Comment: No worries at all! Were you able to read the ciphertext that jwi and I posted? ROT13 is a pretty common (and easily decryptable) cipher that you'll often see in the comments of answers in order to further avoid spoiling the puzzle.

Comment: @El-Guest and jwi were correct! Great first answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not correct, but it could be a

> stop

I am important for flight,

> Well, it's important for a flight to stop. If you don't believe me, listen to George Carlin :D

my anagram will affect your sunlight.

> a spot? Maybe on glasses or on your eye, god forbid

My abbreviation is used to modify,

> s.t. - "such that"

else you would not be able to write Phi.

> Nope... I got nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Also probably not correct, but

> Lifter

I am important for flight,

> Lifters sound important to fly.  Wonder if there is such a thing.

my anagram will affect your sunlight.

> Filter

My abbreviation is used to modify,

> the L you say?

else you would not be able to write Phi.

> well a lowercase l could be the line in ϕ